# How to obtain values from input fields with Angular JS after ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm new in AngulsrJS and I've got following code:

```
<form ng-if="editorCtrl.edit" class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit="editorCtrl.saveEntry()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6" ng-repeat="(key,field) in editorCtrl.editEntry">
            <label>{{key}}</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value={{field}} />
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ng-model="editorCtrl.toSave[key]" ng-value="{{field}}" that part was in input attributes -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <div style="padding-left:110px">
            <input type="submit" value="Update selected entry" ng-disabled="form.$invalid" class="btn btn-primary"/>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Now I need to obtain values from input fields. I tried to use ng-model="editorCtrl.toSave[key], but it's not working in a correct way.

Any suggestions how to resolve this situation ?

Comment: provide your editorCtrl.editEntry data and the way u tried with models

Comment: Well, I can fill inputs with data which I get from editorCtrl.editEntry, it's OK. The problem is, on submit I need to collect this data and store in the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can consider no necesary the "toSave" object maybe you can use the 2-way data binding properly only using editEntry Object :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value={{field}} ng-model="editorCtrl.editEntry[key]"/>
```

In this way after a submit you will get editEntry with the fields modifieds (or not), here is an example

https://jsfiddle.net/pv8qrwty/1/

run the example and if you modified the fields after you press the submit button it will be displayed in your browser console

hope this help ! and sorry for my english !

Comment: Don't worry about English, anyway it's better than mine :)  You solution looks good, but how can I stringify edited editEntry and send it in POST query

Comment: Sorry for previous comment, I was to happy to push F5 button. Everything is working fine. You save my life today! Thank you.

Comment: Hahaha, Great !